# how to add events to default android calendar?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add calendar events in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)

I have to add events to the default calendar control on android phones from my application.

I am making the app for android 2.1 to 2.3.

I have tried out [this](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3850276) tutorial but it does not work.

it is mentioned in the tutorial that the code may not work for android 2.x and above.

I am getting the data from a database for adding events to the calendar.

How do i add events to the default phone calendar in android 2.x?

thank you in advance.