# Need to add event in calender

Tags: android, android-layout

i need to add some event in calendar,example In Aug-15 i need to add "independence celebration ".one i click Aug-15 have to show "independence celebration ",please help me i am in trouble

Comment: Yes dear you are in trouble but please post the code that you have tried yet.

Comment: Please go through this link first because there are many questions for the same exits on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+calendar+event

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android create calendar event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094243/android-create-calendar-event)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions about same calender events.You should have searched the forum at least once before asking it but since you asked I'm giving you a code which you can understand and modify according to your needs.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

If you find any difficulty then you can refer to these previously asked questions:

[How to add calendar events in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)