# Failing at passing in date time to android calendar (@ Oriharel mainly)

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

This is called from a button on a page using webview.  It works great except for passing in the time.  What am I doing wrong?

```
public void addToCalendar( final long startTime, String allday, final long endTime, String title, String myLocation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");                    
                intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.startTime);
                intent.putExtra("allDay", allday);
                intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
                intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.endTime);
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                intent.putExtra("eventLocation",myLocation);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
```

I am getting the date 1/15/1970 10:45pm  and 1/15/1970 10:45pm when i try passing in

```
How do I pass the date time?
```

This is mainly @Oriharel     post [How to add calendar events in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android/4336183#4336183)

Comment: Doesn't this code give a syntax error on `intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.startTime);`? The start time in the post is milliseconds from Jan 1 1970.

Comment: Well thats the thing I have been just intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime);  however my dates and time just come out all funky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it to work.

```
 public void addToCalendar(String startTime, String endTime, String allDay, String title, String myLocation, String descript) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            java.sql.Timestamp ts1 = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(startTime);
            java.sql.Timestamp ts2 = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(endTime);

            long tsTime1 = ts1.getTime();
            long tsTime2 = ts2.getTime();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

                intent.putExtra("beginTime", tsTime1);
                intent.putExtra("allDay", allDay);
                intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
                intent.putExtra("endTime", tsTime2);
                intent.putExtra("title", title);
                intent.putExtra("eventLocation",myLocation);
                intent.putExtra("description", descript);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Well, I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

How do you use parameters startTime and endTime ? Actually you use a new Calendar instance, pointing on now.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: "pointing on now" === what does this mean? was there to be a link here?    And I see the new api http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingSingle   BUT... STILL  how do you pass in the date time I don't see the format.

Comment: I was just saying that you didn't use the parameters of your method and used a new Calendar Object. Anyhow, what are startTime and endTime, how do you get their values ?

Comment: i pass them in via a javascript wrapper in a webview. right now Im trying "2012-08-01T14:00:00"

Comment: they should be long values, so what are their values, as longs.

Answer (score 0):

Posting alternative code as an aid to others on how this can be done. I've hard coded the date string to make the example more clear.

```
private long getEventDateAsLong(String dateToProcess ) {

    Date date = parseDate(dateToProcess); 
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    return ts.getTime(); 

}

private Date parseDate(String date) throws ParseException {     

    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(); 

        try {
    return formatter.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

As I said earlier, I have hard coded two example dates as strings so you can see how it works:

```
String startDateToProcess = "July 3, 2013";
String endDateToProcess = "July 15, 2013";
```

and then wherever you are creating your calendar intent, your code should look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", getEventDateAsLong(startDateToProcess));
intent.putExtra("endTime", getEventDateAsLong(endDateToProcess ));
startActivity(intent);
```