# How to add a calendar event on an Android device with a given date?

Tags: android

From Stack Overflow question *[How to add calendar events in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)* I came to know how to add the calendar event, but with the specific time for starttime (with hour and minutes) and EndTime (with hour and minutes). How can we add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this. Here startDate is the time you want to start.

```
    long startTime,endTime;

    String startDate = "2011-09-01";
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(startDate);
        startTime=date.getTime();
    }
    catch(Exception e){ }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime",startTime);
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
    intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how can i add a URI to a calendar event.. please help, I want to start my app from calendar event..

Answer (score 1):

You can as well use a Calendar instance with the set(year, month, day, hourofday, minofday) method before putextra("beginTime");