# How to get the status of the calendar event set or not

Tags: android

By Stack Overflow question *[How to add a calendar event on an Android device with a given date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160231)* I set the calendar event, but how do I know that the user has set the calendar event or not set it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the user to pick a date? You can use the date picker dialog and a listener. Here is a tutorial which explains you how to do it:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Comment: i want to know that user press the save button calendar event activity or cancel button for not saving the event.means Status of the event,successfully set or not.

Comment: Then you can use StartActivityForResult as shown in this link:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities see the section Starting Activities and Getting Results

Comment: i have test the application by using startActivityForResult,but how we know user press save or cancel.on pressing of save also onActivityResult() is executing and by pressing cancel also.