# How to pass the email id that to be synchronized into create event calendar in android?

Tags: java, android, calendar

How to pass the mail id of the calendar that to be synchronized into the create event through email?
I have a spinner that shows the list of accounts to be synchronized as below picture. Now, as usual passing title,description to create event in calendar application, i use following code.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("calendar_id", 1);
    values.put("title", title1);
    values.put("allDay", 0);
    values.put("dtstart", settime);
    values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000); 
    values.put("description", desc1);
    values.put("???????", mail_id);
    values.put("???????", participant_mail_id);
    values.put("visibility", 0);
    values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
    event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
```

What should i use to pass the key to insert email id and participant id? Any Help is really appreciated. My screen shot goes below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to pass the mail id of the calendar that to be synchronized

The event is linked to a calendar by the "calendar_id". To get the "calendar_id" you should query for all the user's calendars and then search results for name in which you are interested. Here is a tutorial which should help: [Working with the Android Calendar](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm)

Alternatively, you can create an event and then let the user choose to which Calendar the event should be added: [Adding Calendar event through Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android/4336183#4336183)

Comment: Here there is no code to insert the synchronizing attendee mail id and participant mail id into the calendar event?