# Add event to calendar in android

Tags: android, calendar

I need a radio button that says, "Add to calendar", if the option is checked, then present a date control or spinner control to let the user choose a date. Once the user chooses a date, it should add the notes feature to the calendar.

Any examples, solutions, or links would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For datepicker, a standard widget is available. See [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html).

For adding this to the calendar, I'm assuming that you want to add it to the native calendar. I'd suggest going through a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)