# How to Add an event in Google Calendar from Activity?

Tags: android, events, google-calendar-api

I tried using content providers, but the event was not added to the calendar.

```
final ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();    
cv.put("calendar_id", l_calId);    
cv.put("title", title);    
cv.put("description", description);    
cv.put("dtstart", millis1 );    
cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);   
cv.put("dtend", millis2);    
cv.put("eventLocation", "Hall: "+location);    
cv.put("transparency", 1);    
cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);    


Uri newEvent ;    
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) == 8 )    
    newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), cv);    
else    
    newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), cv);
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want to add an event to your users' calendar, the (unsupported) way of doing it on Android 2.x is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336183/1101070).

As of Android 4.0, the practice changed while breaking support for the unsupported way as documented [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html). This was replaced by an official API working on ICS and onwards which is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html).