# How to set date and time in a specific format

Tags: android, datetime

Usibg this code I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DTSTART cannot be empty`. This error is coming from:

**code:**

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                String eventTime="12:00:AM 11:59:PM";
                String[] time=eventTime.split(" ");
                String[] execttime=time[0].split(":");
                String eventStartDate="06 Feb 2014"+" " + execttime[0]+":"+execttime[1]+":00";
                long startDate=getDateCurrentMillis(eventStartDate);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
                        startDate);
                Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(EventDetail.this)+ "events");

    public static long getDateCurrentMillis(String startDate) {

        SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",

        Locale.getDefault());

        sfd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        try {

            Date d = sfd.parse(startDate);

            return d.getTime();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("");

        }    
    return 0;
        }
```

Comment: DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, h:mm a");String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening in your `getDateCurrentMillis` method. Is it not able to parse the date because of incorrect format specified in `SimpleDateFormat`, which result in returning 0 all the time. Passing 0 in DTSTART crashing your app.

It seems your eventStartDate is in format like this

```
String date = "06 Feb 2014 12:00:00";
```

So make your SimpleDateFormat object in a way like this

```
SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
```

Let me know if I observed your date format correctly, If not print it before passing and make changes accordingly in your `SimpleDateFormat` object or post in comment I will make necessary changes.

Comment: If i want that event is add in android calender from 13Feb 12:00:00PM to 18Feb 01:00:00 So how in which format it is set

Comment: TO insert in Android Calendar you have to pass date and time in millis as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914759/how-to-add-event-in-google-calendar-from-android-application To convert in millis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914759/how-to-add-event-in-google-calendar-from-android-application

Comment: i have done it but i want that on every day added event is alert from 12:00:00 PM to 01:00:00 PM

Comment: String startEventTime=UIUtils.getCurrentTime(time[0]);
    String endEventTime=UIUtils.getCurrentTime(time[1]);
    String eventStartDate=eventSDate+" " + startEventTime;
    String eventEndDate=eventEDate+" "+endEventTime;
    long startDate=getDateCurrentMillis(eventStartDate);
    long endDate=getDateCurrentMillis(eventEndDate);

Comment: public static long getDateCurrentMillis(String startDate) {

  // 2013-10-24T01:00:00Z

  SimpleDateFormat sfd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",

  Locale.getDefault());

  sfd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

  try {

   Date d = sfd.parse(startDate);

   return d.getTime();

  } catch (Exception e) {

   System.out.println("");

  }

  return 0;

 }

Comment: It would be better if you include it in question reading code in comments is quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, h:mm a");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //to pick date 
  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
        }
        }



//to pick time

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            updateLabel();
        }
        };
```

for more information use this link

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1520