# PhoneGap Android Calendar Integration

Tags: android, cordova

I want help with integration pf my phone gap application to interact with the native calendar in android.Am stuck at this point.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android/10310258#10310258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked quite some time ago, but the accepted answer isn't accurate nowadays.

On September 2013 Eddy Verbruggen created a nice PhoneGap / Cordova plugin for this purpose.
You can find all the information in the following link:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap does not allow for calendar integration. Take a look here for phonegap supported features:
http://phonegap.com/about/feature

You might want to take a look at Rhomobile which seems to support a system calendar:
http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#pim-calendarevents