# How to Read and Write Calendar event in Froyo And above Froyo OS in Android

Tags: android

I have some problem of inserting new or edit event by grammatically. Android Foryo os 2.2 working fine but same things is not run in ICS. I know the `ContentProvider` url but error is on Column field.

Please help me or post your Code or samples.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample for editing a new event:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", myStringTitle);
intent.putExtra("description", myStringDescription);
intent.putExtra("eventLocation",myStringLocation);
intent.putExtra("beginTime", myBeginDate.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("endTime", myEndDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this code is working fine but that calendar also opened when i execute this code. I have to add the events without showing the calendar to the user