# Add event in android native clander from my application and sync

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to make an application for my calender events what I want to do is when i will create an event on my server the same should be automatically added in the android native calender using my application so is it possible to add events in android default calender using a third party application if yes how it can be implemented ?

I am planning to use Google push notification to push the event details or is there any API so that the calender will automatically sync like same for Gmail calenders and facebook calender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to add events in android default calender using a third
>   party application if yes how it can be implemented ?

=> Yes It's possible through either `Calendar` content provider (for Android 4.0) or `CalendarContract` (For Android >4.0) content provider.

check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCalendar/article.html) for CalendarContract example and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336183/379693) for Calendar content provider

Comment: I am having these two in the link you replied `eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);`
`eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);` how to put dates in that ?

Comment: @pyus13 how to put means? Both the examples have proper code for the same, have you checked both?

Comment: ya i have checked. but I got some thing from other link actually the given link is about to set for today but i need to set it on some particular date and time `cal.set(date and time)` helped me for the same  thanks a lot.