# Firemonkey Android Access Calendar and Events

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

How do I access the Calendar and Events on Android using Delphi XE5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the calendar you can use the [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class which is represented by the `JCalendar` class in Delphi.

You can find a set of samples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)

And this is a Delphi sample

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  Calendar: JCalendar;
begin
  Calendar := TJCalendar.JavaClass.getInstance;
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setType(StringToJString('vnd.android.cursor.item/event'));
  intent.putExtra(StringToJString('beginTime'), Calendar.getTimeInMillis());
  intent.putExtra(StringToJString('allDay'), true);
  intent.putExtra(StringToJString('rrule'), StringToJString('FREQ=YEARLY'));
  intent.putExtra(StringToJString('endTime'), Calendar.getTimeInMillis()+3600*1000);
  intent.putExtra(StringToJString('title'), StringToJString('Hello from Delphi'));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Comment: In Delphi XE6 StringToJString is declared in Androidapi.Helpers, so this unit also must be used.

Comment: This code does not work anymore for new Delphi/GoogleApi version. Does anyone have updated solution?

Comment: You have to add the action: ACTION_INSERT in order to make this code work. Otherwise it only opens the calendar and does not insert an event.

Answer (score 0):

in XE5 they started with PlatformServices and put Pickers Service into it: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Pickers.IFMXPickerService

probably this piece of code will be usable for you:

```
  var
      PickerService: IFMXPickerService;
    begin
       if PlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(
           IFMXPickerService, Interface(PickerService))
    then
        FDateTimePicker := PickerService.CreateDateTimePicker;
        ...   // or
        FListPicker := PickerService.CreateListPicker;
```