# FireMonkey: opening image with native gallery

Tags: android, delphi, gallery, firemonkey

I've got a Firemonkey mobile application using Delphi XE6. The app can take photos from camera or library (using standard actions) and display them on the form. I would now like to display the image when I click on it. The simplest way for that seems to open it with the native gallery app.

From what I gathered from my searches, the way to do it in Eclipse with Java (OnClick method) would be something like this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
```

This obviously wouldn't work in Delphi (unless I can use the Androidapi somehow? is that possible?), but there has got to be some other way of doing it in a FMX way of thinking. I've searched through the standard actions and available components but can't seem to find any way of opening the photo with the gallery.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it's possible to use Android intents, see an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19186534/11480).

Comment: Hmm that's a great help, thanks. I still wonder if there is a FMX way of doing it though.