# Android 2.3.3 Creating Events in Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want to add to my application the ability for the user to create events at specific dates. I've looked around on the internet and on SO, and found out that android 2.3.3 does not have calendar, so I need to use a custom calendar. I've looked around and found some, but they don't support creating events. I've also read about `CalendarProvider` but it didn't work with the custom calendars. Can someone please recommend me an open-source custom calendar for android 2.3.3 that support creating events.
Thanks

EDIT: Or if there is some kind of tutorial on how I can make my own custom calendar that would  be helpful too.

Comment: Just checking – Have you tried Oriharel's answer in [/q/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)?

Comment: Yes I tried it, in fact I got an error from it, the application just stopped.