# Android Calendar invitation

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to create a simple application on Android that only have a button and when I click it it will add an event to the calendar with reminder and attendees. I follow Pradeep's answer in this one: [How to add calendar events in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android) and I get everything correctly, the event is at the right time with the reminder and attendees list. But the problem I have is that it dont send any kind of notice/invitation to the attendees (ofc it dont show up in their calendar as well), which is what I want to do, so anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Event is added successfully into the calendar.The issue is not get any notification for the user or ?

Comment: For getting the local notification u have to set the alarmmanager using broadcast receiver and in broadcast receiver u have to set the notification

Comment: Event is added successfully, but the other person I added in as attendee dont get the notification/email to notified it like if I normally adding guest in google calendar.

Also I noticed something. I'm using a Note 3, which have the default calendar is the SPlanner, which dont have that adding attendee/guest function that the google calendar have, so maybe because my program adding the events to the default S Planner so there's no notification? If so then is there anyway to force the app I made to choose google calendar instead of the default one?

Comment: check the link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

Comment: Did u register the ur application for push ? check the above link for that

Comment: code for register the tab in  google is http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you want is [localNotification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)