# How to share events from Calendar app

Tags: android, ios, calendar, share

I need to share events from Calendar app (Android and iOS) using a file that users can download in their devices. Anyone knows if is that possible?.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calendar is not an app used for sharing something. I guess you want to add event to a calendar app. See this for an example code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310258/5250273