# Google Calendar event hides after some time

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

This is my code related to Google Calendar inserting event :

```
private void insertData() {

    long calID = 3;
    long startMillis = 0;
    long endMillis = 0;
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2017,Calendar.OCTOBER, 12, 10, 30);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2017, Calendar.OCTOBER, 15, 15, 45);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, "GroupThing");
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");

    Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```

It inserts events in the calendar, but after sometime, it automatically gets deleted.

Does anyone know what is causing problem ?

Comment: did you anywhere write a delete method for _uri_?

Comment: The community [recently discussed adding requests for urgency to questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and decided that we prefer questions without such designations.

Comment: no, i didn't write any delete method for uri

Comment: Is your calendar synced to other devices? It's suggested in the [productforums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/calendar/calendar-not-loading/JEi6Oo5Ve_U) that it may be a cause of the issue.