# How to save entry to native calendar (Android & iOS ) in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, nscalendar

I am looking to save an entry to the native calendar through my app. I have all the entry details such as Name, time/date, location etc . Is there something i can use out of the box in react native. If not are there any existing plugins available for this functionality?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android) and also [this](http://sureshdotariya.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-add-events-to-native-calendar.html) it may be of some help to you

Answer (score 2):

A quick search in [js.coach](https://js.coach/react-native/react-native-calendar-manager?search=calendar) suggested me these packages:

- [react-native-calendarevents-android](https://github.com/Exilz/react-native-calendarevents-android)
- [rncm](https://github.com/bilalkosker/rncm)

In addition to that, check [this tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/native-modules-ios.html#ios-calendar-module-example) out (iOS only, but it might be of use).