# Android CalendarView with events

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm looking for a CalendarView that can be used to **show multiple events**, like the Google Calendar.

I haven't found a solution for this using `android.widget.CalendarView`.

What is the best way to implement this feature? Should I customize `android.widget.CalendarView` or should i use an existing library (which one)?

[image]

Comment: Try to use given link solutions or suggestions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android?rq=1

Comment: Try to use this solution or suggestions. [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use existing library as you can refer here http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-calendarview-example.html

for more customize you can use this library
 https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: I am not able to display the events(through JSON Data) within the Calendar. how can this be Solved?

Answer (score 2):

Hello i used this github project it may serve you as a guide! [Calendar View](https://github.com/hugomfandrade/CalendarView-Widget)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231

Comment: This seems to be a good widget. Unfortunately, I am no longer working on the project.