# Android CalendarView issue

Tags: java, android, oop, calendar

In my android studio project where I am using CalendarView I want to display events on day button. So how can I highlight the day button so the user will know the particular date contain events?

**Expected output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this API in your code.. It will help u to insert event, event with reminder and event with meeting can be enabled... This api works for platform 2.1 and above Those who uses less then 2.1 instead of content://com.android.calendar/events use content://calendar/events

```
public static long pushAppointmentsToCalender(Activity curActivity, String title, String addInfo, String place, int status, long startDate, boolean needReminder, boolean needMailService) {
/***************** Event: note(without alert) *******************/

String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1); // id, We need to choose from
                                    // our mobile for primary
                                    // its 1
eventValues.put("title", title);
eventValues.put("description", addInfo);
eventValues.put("eventLocation", place);

long endDate = startDate + 1000 * 60 * 60; // For next 1hr

eventValues.put("dtstart", startDate);
eventValues.put("dtend", endDate);

// values.put("allDay", 1); //If it is bithday alarm or such
// kind (which should remind me for whole day) 0 for false, 1
// for true
eventValues.put("eventStatus", status); // This information is
// sufficient for most
// entries tentative (0),
// confirmed (1) or canceled
// (2):
eventValues.put("eventTimezone", "UTC/GMT +2:00");
```

/*Comment below visibility and transparency  column to avoid java.lang.IllegalArgumentException column visibility is invalid error */

```
/*eventValues.put("visibility", 3); // visibility to default (0),
                                    // confidential (1), private
                                    // (2), or public (3):
eventValues.put("transparency", 0); // You can control whether
                                    // an event consumes time
                                    // opaque (0) or transparent
                                    // (1).
  */
eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true

Uri eventUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

if (needReminder) {
    /***************** Event: Reminder(with alert) Adding reminder to event *******************/

    String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";

    ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

    reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
    reminderValues.put("minutes", 5); // Default value of the
                                        // system. Minutes is a
                                        // integer
    reminderValues.put("method", 1); // Alert Methods: Default(0),
                                        // Alert(1), Email(2),
                                        // SMS(3)

    Uri reminderUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);
}

/***************** Event: Meeting(without alert) Adding Attendies to the meeting *******************/

if (needMailService) {
    String attendeuesesUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/attendees";

    /********
     * To add multiple attendees need to insert ContentValues multiple
     * times
     ***********/
    ContentValues attendeesValues = new ContentValues();

    attendeesValues.put("event_id", eventID);
    attendeesValues.put("attendeeName", "xxxxx"); // Attendees name
    attendeesValues.put("attendeeEmail", "yyyy@gmail.com");// Attendee
                                                                        // E
                                                                        // mail
                                                                        // id
    attendeesValues.put("attendeeRelationship", 0); // Relationship_Attendee(1),
                                                    // Relationship_None(0),
                                                    // Organizer(2),
                                                    // Performer(3),
                                                    // Speaker(4)
    attendeesValues.put("attendeeType", 0); // None(0), Optional(1),
                                            // Required(2), Resource(3)
    attendeesValues.put("attendeeStatus", 0); // NOne(0), Accepted(1),
                                                // Decline(2),
                                                // Invited(3),
                                                // Tentative(4)

    Uri attendeuesesUri = curActivity.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(attendeuesesUriString), attendeesValues);
}

return eventID;
```

}

Hope that helps you

For further information you may refer below link
[How to add calendar events in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)

Comment: Can you please elaborate this code. I'm unable to use this. @Abdul Waheed