# Reminding a user by using a particular date and time in any of the screen in my application

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

In Android 4.0.x we can use `CalendarView`. Using that functionality, I need to develop a reminder task.

By clicking the particular date, I need to pop-up the `TimePicker` and after selection of the specific time, the date and time needs to be stored in the database.

The background process needs to check the reminder time with the current time for every minute and if it has matched with the current time, the alarm needs to be raised on whichever screen is on the front side.

That means, if my project contains multiple tasks and each task has separate pages, I may work on any page after setting the reminder. I need to show the alarm on the front of the screen in any instance.

If my tablet is in sleep or switched off mode, the alarm must shown when I switch on my tablet.

Comment: In this i need to store the Reminders in my database for future references.

Comment: Otherwise can i develop this Reminder application using 'CalendarContract.Reminders'

Comment: This is not a question, but rather just a wish list of what you want your program to do. If you have a specific question please be more clear about what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can save both the context and the events in a singletone and then you will have access to the current context from the activity that is running at any given point.

If you need to start your app after the phone switches on, take a look here: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/

If you need something more specific just ask,

Regards

Comment: In this, How to create a Reminder Process with the Calendar or CalendarView.

Comment: check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642135/programmatically-add-reminder-in-android-calendar