# AlarmManager at specific date and time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'd like to show a dialog at specific date and time (25/12/2012 at 12.00) and I am using this code. I set like 11 month (because 0 is gen) but the alarm does not start. What is my mistake?

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,25);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

Intent _myIntent = new Intent(context, Notify.class);
    PendingIntent _myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, _myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), _myPendingIntent);
```

Comment: is it working for anyone? I'm struggling but not working.

Answer (score 8):

Look at below code about how i am going to set the alarm for the December month:

```
// for Alarm 25/12/2012 at 12.00   
Calendar myAlarmDate = Calendar.getInstance();
myAlarmDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
myAlarmDate.set(2012, 11, 25, 12, 00, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent _myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverNotificationForEveryMonth.class);
_myIntent.putExtra("MyMessage","HERE I AM PASSING THEPERTICULAR MESSAGE WHICH SHOULD BE SHOW ON RECEIVER OF ALARM");
PendingIntent _myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, _myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myAlarmDate.getTimeInMillis(),_myPendingIntent);
```

You can update the above code with your intent and class and you will get your desire output.

Hope this help you.

Comment: You have to setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()) with accurate date, month and time

Comment: I prefer work on my code because I'll be confuse with other code. Thanks.

Comment: @PolHallen: please see my answer now. I have updated code as per your requirement. Just paste that code and see. It works for me.

Comment: Just a minor correction: It SHOULD be myAlarmDate.set(2012, 12, 25, 12, 00, 0); and NOT myAlarmDate.set(2012, 11, 25, 12, 00, 0); as you are targeting December and not November.

Comment: @UncaughtException hey you are wrong. In month section calendar must be 0 base. So december is 11, not 12.

Comment: @MahbuburRahmanKhan You are getting it wrong. The formate is Year, Month, Date, Hours, Minutes, Seconds. So as per that 11 is the month.

Comment: Yes here 11 is month. May be you do not read my comment properly, comment is for @uncought exception, not for you. I only say that,  11 means december month, not november because month start to count 0.

Comment: @MahbuburRahmanKhan It seems you edit your comment. Anway not an issue.

Comment: Not need myAlarmDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); because Calendar.getInstance(); already set calender to current date time.